# Fetching user-related details and multifactor authentication methods for specific users or all users using powershell mg-graph

Tags: powershell-2.0

Fetching user-related details and multifactor authentication methods for specific users or all users using powershell mg-graph

Written function to get the user details using MG-Graph but not able to get the output please help me on this as i am new to PowerShell. able to get the details if the script is not placed in a function, when placing the script in function the script takes time to execute and it taking more than 1hr.
tried with jobs but not knowing how that helps.